# Is this the correct way to enumerate over an array, looking for a potential object to store into a variable?

Tags: swift

I was struggling to come up with a concise title, but I think the problem is pretty straight forward:

```
        var selectedModule: Module? = nil
        for module in ModuleList.modulesArray {
            if module.name == selectedModuleName {
                selectedModule = module
            }
        }
        if let moduleFound = selectedModule {
            _set(model: &viewModel.module, button: moduleButton, displayedValue: selectedModuleName, actualValue: moduleFound)
        }
```

This is what I have now, and it works, but I come from Obj-C and this feels weird

I want to enumerate over `ModuleList.modulesArray`, and potentially store an object into `selectedModule`

This of course means that `selectedModule` could be `nil`, so I made it an Optional

But then I have to go and unwrap it with optional binding, `if let moduleFound = selectedModule`

Is this really the best way to go about this? 
Seems to be the case, but I'm just double-checking as I am very new to Swift

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, that is not the best solution. The optional variable can be
avoided completely.

If you are only interested in the first matching module then
you can use the `first(where:)` method which returns the first
element satisfying the predicate, or `nil` if no such element exists.
The return value is checked with optional binding:

```
if let selectedModule = modulesArray.first(where: { $0.name == selectedModuleName }) {
    // Do something with selectedModule ...
} else {
    // No matching module
}
```

If you are interested in *all* matching modules then you can
use a `for` loop with a `where` constraint:

```
for module in modulesArray where module.name == selectedModuleName {
    // Do something with module ...
}
```

Comment: Beautiful, that's exactly what I was looking for!  saved me 6 lines.   Funny thing is I read that off a Swift book, but totally didn't think to use it